# UIButton not receiving touches

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

While making my first app I tried to make a button inside a view.
There is a stack view with 3 equally distributed views in it. In one if them there is a button. But when I run my app my button is not receiving touches: print does not work and there is no animation.
Any advice where to check?
[image]

**Update1**
Following @florentin-lupascu advice I tried to remove the link from Sent event, but to no avail.
Here is my project in GitHub https://github.com/Koshmariel/IntervalTimer.git

[image]

**Update2**
Also there is one more strange thing - background color is set in all 3 views. In Xcode all looks as it should while in emulator only the top container background is applied.[image]

**Update3**
I moved my button to the TopView and it started to work. Still no clue why it is not working in the BottomView while working in TopView.

Comment: make new view controller and assign to your view from storyboard then create your action again with touch up inside event. it's may be xcode bug i was getting same issue but later it was fixed without any change but can try the above solution. hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side (View Controllers Scene) right click on your `START` button and check what `Sent Events` are linked under `Touch up inside` section. Try to click the small `X` button to remove the reference and to link again your button. If you can upload on GitLab your small project will be more easy for us to see where is the problem and to help you understand what was wrong. Because on that screenshot everything looks correctly.

Comment: edited initial post